# drop decimal in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateRandomNumber();

    }

    public static void generateRandomNumber(){

        double[] insideArray = new double[5];

        for(int i=0; i<insideArray.length; i++) {
            double value = (Math.random()+1)*10;
            insideArray[i] = value;
            String.format("%.2f", insideArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Displaying random generated Array: " + Arrays.toString(insideArray));

    }

}
```

I am trying to generate 5 random numbers and store to an Array.  And I would like to format decimals up to 2 numbers. I tried "String.format()" method but didn't work. Still I am getting double like: 10.xxxxxxxxxxx.

How can I format it such as ex:
10.xx
?

Comment: in your code, where do you put the formated String value?

Comment: `String.format("%.2f", insideArray[i]);` - this returns a string which you do nothing with. You need to assign it to something.

Comment: `insideArray[i] = ((long) (value * 100)) / 100.0;`

Comment: Not a duplicate, the method used for rounding is good. This is a discard-returned-value issue, not a rounding issue

Comment: Ok thanks for your attentions. I found the solution :  Double.parseDouble() method worked for me.

Comment: @jhamon then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) could be an appropriate duplicate

Answer (score 2):

`String.format(String, double);` returns the formated String. It doesn't change the object you want to format.

In other words: `insideArray[i]` is still an unrounded double after calling `String.format`.

The easiest way to solve your issue would be to store the result of `String.format`inside the array. But the result is a `String` and the array is a `double` array. Those type don't match.

You can either declare a second array to store the strings, or simply change the type of `insideArray`, as it seems you don't do anything further with its elements.

**Solution A:**

```
double[] insideArray = new double[5];
String[] myStringArray = new String[5];

for(int i=0; i<insideArray.length; i++) {
    double value = (Math.random()+1)*10;
    insideArray[i] = value;
    myStringArray[i] = String.format("%.2f", insideArray[i]);
}
System.out.println("Displaying random generated Array: " + Arrays.toString(myStringArray));
```

**Solution B:**

```
String[] insideArray = new String[5];

for(int i=0; i<insideArray.length; i++) {
    double value = (Math.random()+1)*10;
    insideArray[i] =String.format("%.2f", value);
}
System.out.println("Displaying random generated Array: " + Arrays.toString(insideArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print a double varible it can't be always limit to 2 decimal digits. Either use BigDecimal or store it in the form of string.

```
 public static void generateRandomNumber(){
        String [] insideArray = new String[5];   // double array to string array    
            for(int i=0; i<insideArray.length; i++) {
                double value = (Math.random()+1)*10;               
                insideArray[i] = String.format("%.2f", value);  // store the converted number in the form of string.            
            }
            System.out.println("Displaying random generated Array: " + Arrays.toString(insideArray));    
        }
```